# How do I get a HttpServletRequest object when loading a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a HTML page that allows me to use JSP code. I was able to print some output using some basic Java. But How do I obtain a  HttpServletRequest object so I can print some of its properties onto the HTML page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `request` variable (`HttpServletRequest` instance). It is one of *implicit objects*  in JSP. Check properties here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

```
<%
    request.getHeader();
%>
```